# How to install Ubuntu touch on LG E617G Optimus L5

Tags: installation, ubuntu-touch, compiling, bootloader

I have been tinkering with my LG Optimus L5 E617G and can't seem to find any good instructions on how to install Ubuntu Touch or even get to the bootloader to do so... If anyone has any suggestions please help me out????

Answer (score 0):

At the moment it is only working with the following devices:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Devices

I'm sorry, hope it helped solve your doubt.